# Real Numbers expressing in terms of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

From the literature, I have found the following:
Any real number A (say) can be expressed as

$ A = a_1 + (1/a_1) + (1/a_2) + (1/a_3) +\ldots$
Where $a_1\ge2$ and the recurrence relation $a_{i+1}\ge a_i(a_i - 1) + 1$ for $i \ge 1$.

I could not understand this statement due to the fowling reason:

I fixed $a_1$ = 2 then, $A = 2 + ½ + (1/a_2) + (1/a_3) + \dots$     ---------(i)

We can find $a_2$  by recurrence relation; $a_2 \ge a_1(a_1 -1) + 1 = 2(2-1) + 1 = 3$

i.e., $a_2\ge 3$ and $a_3\ge4$ and so on…
Now, by our (i), $A = 2 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + \dots$

How any real number A is equal to (i)?

I could not understand this statement.

Also, the same A can be expressible in other two ways:

$A =  a_0 + (1/a_1) + (1/a_1)(1/a_2) + (1/a_1)(1/a_2)(1/a_3)+ \ldots$
Where $a_1\ge2$ and recurrence relation $a_{i+1}\ge a_i$ for $i \ge1$.

Also, $$A =  a_0 + (1/a_1) + (1/(a_1-1)) (1/a_1) (1/a_2) \\+ (1/(a_1-1)) ((1/a_2-1)) (1/a_1)(1/a_2)(1/a_3) +\ldots$$

Briefly, explain where I am wrong in my example or not? Also, how to deduce one equation to other equations of A? A waiting your explanations and proofs.

**Edit**
Is it applicable for any **GIVEN** real number, instead of any real number? If yes, how to proceed to complete the proof? can we deduce from one representation to other representations?

Comment: Could you tell us where "in the literature" you found this? It might help us if we could see where this comes from.

Comment: The point is not that every series of the form you have given represents a real number, but that any real number can be expressed in the series form. As you have shown there are possible series which don't express real numbers.

Comment: The first series is unusual and your later examples have different notation - should it begin with $a_0$?

Comment: If we are to take this at face value, real numbers $\le2$ don't exist. Curious.

Comment: On a side note, your use of TeX is really odd. You're supposed to put dollar signs around entire formulas, not just around small bits of formula. And you can get $\ge$ by typing `\ge`. I fixed it up as best I could; please look it over to make sure I did not accidentally change the meaning.

Comment: OLD JOHN SIR, Literature means, I studied in my text as one of the note at the end of the chapter. That chapter name is writing real numbers in infinite series.

Comment: Yes, but which **book** does it come from? Who is the author?

Comment: HARALD HANCHE OLSEN SIR, I will use latex properly in next time. Thank you for editing the post.

Comment: MARK BENNET SIR, may be $a_0$ is need. I am not sure. but, can we express the same for any given  real number?

Comment: As you have it there is no way of expressing zero (or any negative number, or indeed any real number less than 2.5) ... if you had $a_0$ the situation would be rather different, so you see it does matter what the statement is, and no-one will be able to answer unless you clarify the various matters noted in the comments.

Comment: @MarkBennet As a matter of fact, it is not so difficult to guess what would be a correct formulation of the first statement (and to prove it)... But I fully agree that the OP should first clarify (and maybe, o foolish hope, answer OldJohn's question about the source).

Comment: @did Indeed not, and I was rather hoping that the person who asked the question would put in a little work to do this, rather than being told. There are some interesting things to investigate around these egyptian fraction type decompositions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you are saying that real $A$ has a single representation as $$A = a_0 + (1/a_1) + (1/a_2) + (1/a_3) +\cdots$$ for integer $a_i$ where $a_1\ge2$ and the recurrence relation $a_{i+1}\ge a_i(a_i - 1) + 1$ for $i \ge 1$.

This is (at least for irrational $A$) often described as the Egyptian fraction representation: for example [OEIS A001466](http://oeis.org/A001466) gives $$\pi = 3 + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{61} + \frac{1}{5020} + \frac{1}{128541455}+\cdots .$$

To show it exists and is unique, consider the partial sum $A_i$ up to the $(1/a_i)$ term, where $a_0 = \lceil{A}\rceil - 1$ and $a_{i+1}=\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{A-A_i}}\right\rfloor +1 $.

A proof will use the following points:

- $A_i \lt A \le A_{i-1} + \frac{1}{a_i - 1}$
- $\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$
- if $b_{j+1}= b_j(b_j - 1) + 1$ then $\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b_j} = \frac{1}{b_k -1}$

Your second expression can be handled in a similar way with suitable adjustments: for example the third bullet point becomes $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{b_k}\right)^j =  \frac{1}{b_k -1}$.

Comment: HENRY Sir,  you have added some good flavor to my post. Can you prove the my initial statement? I confused. please do not give hints. Prove the fist statement and then I will try for other two statements of A.

Comment: Sir! can you make proof of (i) by using your bullets?

Comment: Henry Sir, can you make proof of (i) by using your bullets?

Comment: Sir, kindly look at the proof of first part. Becoz, I applied your bullets. But those bullets are not enough to complete the proofs. Please look. I am waiting for your solution.

Comment: @vidyaojal You will understand better why this leads to  a proof if you experiment with various values of $A$ and use  $a_0 = \lceil{A}\rceil - 1$ and $a_{i+1}=\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{A-A_i}}\right\rfloor +1 $, keeping track of $A-A_i$ and $\frac{1}{A-A_i}$

Comment: HENRY Sir, numerically you are very much correct. I checked with several examples. However, we need to prove mathematically instead of taking different values to A. So, find a proof and discuss. Thank you for your previous solution/hints. Kindly do the rest by giving a proof. please...

Comment: ! can you complete any one of the proof of A?please...

Comment: Henry Sir, can you complete any one of the proof of A?please...