# Real number in terms of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is just continuation of my [previous post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187774/real-numbers-expressing-in-terms-of-series)

$$ A = a_0 + \left(\frac{1}{a_1}\right)^k + \left(\frac{1}{a_2}\right)^k + \left(\frac{1}{a_3}\right)^k +\ldots$$
Where $i\ge1$ and the recurrence relation $a_{i+1}\ge a_i\ge2$.

I just raised for each term by $k$. here $k\ge1$ and $A$ is any given real number. Then the above series will exist.  Can we generalize this series of some real number with those initial conditions? If yes, kindly discuss...

**edit**
The first term is $a_0$ but not $a_1$. Of course I edited now.

**Edited and extended**
$$ A = a_0 + \left(\frac{1}{a_1}\right)^k + \left(\frac{1}{a_1}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{a_2}\right)^k + \left(\frac{1}{a_1}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{a_2}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{a_3}\right)^k +\ldots$$

Where $a_1$ = 2, $a_i$$\ge1$ and 2 $\ge$ $a_i$ for $i\ge2$ with $a_i$ = 2. Again, here k $\ge1$ and k is some fised real number. Can you generalize with an example of this modified series?

Comment: What does $k$ add? From the looks of it I can always choose $k=1$ and just pick my constants differently to "simulate" any power of some other series that I like.

Comment: @Robert Mastragostino! not exactly k =1. here the statement is valid for all  k > or = 1. Of course, k is fixed real number.

Comment: Maybe you could link to your previous post?

Comment: @celtschk! you can see the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187774/real-numbers-expressing-in-terms-of-series

Comment: @vidyaojal: Thank you. I've edited it into the question, so that others don't need the comments to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that from your condition it is allowed that $a_{i+1}=a_i$, if $k$ is integer, you can reduce the problem for $k>1$ to the case $k=1$ by repeating $1/a_i^k$ for $a_i^{k-1}$ times before using a new value. By doing that repetition, you get a sum of $a_i^{k-1}/a_i^k = 1/a_i$.

Example:

Say your $k=1$ expansion is
$$A = 1 + 1/2 + 1/8 + \dots$$
and $k=2$. Then your new expansion reads
$$\begin{align}
A &= 1 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\\
&\phantom{= 1} + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2\\
&\phantom{= 1} + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 +\dots
\end{align}$$

Since every real number can be written as the product of an integer and a real number in the range $[1,2)$, the same strategy can be used to reduce the problem for arbitrary non-integer $k>1$ to the problem $1<k<2$.

Comment: Although in the comments above, the poster has stated that $k$ is a fixed real number, not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @Old John: I didn't notice that. For me, the name choice of $k$ together with it being an exponent suggested that it's an integer (well, strictly speaking, he also didn't specify that the $a_i$ are integers, therefore one could just choose $a_0$ as appropriate real number, no matter what the rest of the series converges to ...

Comment: I agree that the question needs to be defined much more clearly!

Comment: OK, I now edited the answer so that I make explicit that this method is only for integer $k$ (and added that it also can be used to reduce the general problem of non-integer $k$ to the problem of $1<k<2$).

Comment: @celtschk! Thank you for your post and editing. I am looking for generalization of the statement for all k >  or  = 1. I am not looking for an example. Kindly do the generalization of A for K > = 1.

Comment: @vidyaojal: I've not just given an example, I've added an example for the *general rule* for integer $k>1$ I've given (that is, I've generalized it for all integer $k$ with $k>1$), and I also said that for non-integer $k$ the same strategy can be used to reduce the prtoblem to the (probably simpler) case $1<k<2$ (this case I didn't solve, however). That is, I've solved the problem completely for integer $k$ and gave a possible step in solving it for non-integer $k$. That's definitely more than just giving an example. I admit it is not a *complete* solution for your problem, though.

Comment: @vidyaojal: BTW, I just now notice that with the conditions as given, no $A<2$ can be written that way (because your condition $a_i\ge 2$ doesn't exclude $a_0$)

Comment: @celtschk! you are right. I just modified the same with little more terms. Can you generalize with your example? Please... also, thank you so much for your QUICK attempt.

Comment: @celtschk!please look at the re-edited one and answer...

Comment: @sorry, I do not have enough points to chat. So, discuss for my new extended post.

Comment: @celtschk! Are you there Sir? Please see my new edited post and respond strictly on it.

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting your question and intent correctly -- which is probably not the case -- then yes. In fact, all real numbers can be defined in terms of (Cauchy-) converging sequences of rational numbers.

I am sure that you already know that a series is a just sequence of partial sums so that, in a given base, the "power-series" representation of a number is just a converging sequence of rational numbers. For example, the decimal expansion of pi is 3.1459... . We could view this as the limit of the rational sequence {3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.145, ...}.

A classic way to define a real number is by a sequence of rational numbers whose successive differences converge to zero ("Cauchy convergence").

Comment: ! you are right and I studied the same after your post. Can you look my series and generalize?

Comment: ! can you apply the same for my post?

Comment: Koarik! r u there? Please see my new edited post and respond strictly on it.